# How to create a nuxt +ssr:false project?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a nuxt3 project
in nuxt.config.js

```js
    import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";
    import path from "path";
    import fs from "fs";
    
    export default defineNuxtConfig({
      builder: "webpack",
      ssr: false,
    
      hooks: {
        "build:done": (builder) => {
          const extraFilePath = path.join(
            builder.nuxt.options.buildDir + "/dist/server",
            "server.mjs"
          );
          fs.writeFileSync(extraFilePath, "export {};");
        },
      },
    });
```

everything works in `yarn dev`
but if yarn build then

```bash
set HOST=127.0.0.1&&node ./.output/server/index.mjs
```

nothing is displayed on 127.0.0.1:3000 but why - it works with ssr:true

Comment: If you're going for an SPA project only, you need to `ssr: false` and `yarn generate` (for SSG). There is no point into taking the SSR part and using a Node.js server just for an SPA.

Comment: For SSG project, I recommend using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve to try your locally generated project.

Comment: but yarn generate didn't generate a server...
Should I use external node+express?

Comment: Why do you need a server if you're going SPA? No point into that since an SPA is a static entrypoint.